# Can Outlook Interop API not recognise a DeliveryNotification

Tags: api, interop, outlook, outlook-addin

Story goes: My user sends an email to their client. My user ticks of "delivery notification" / "read notification". The client responds on the notification. Now my user has a "notification" sitting in their inbox. My application may attach that "email" to a project database, happens with any other regular email.

Now a bug report ticks in (feature request) on my table. My user like to attach those "notifications" to the project in question, but my application does not recognise the notification as an email.

Having recieved this feature/bug request, I start investigating. When I right click the mail in question I'd expect to have the option of attaching the mail to a project. I do with regular emails, but not with the notification email.

First off: Isn't a delivery/ read notification just like any other email. Apparently not as it is not being recognised in the first run.
Second: If it isn't an email, what is it then. Apparently it does not exist. WT'bip'...

I found an enum `DeliveryNotificationOptions` under `System.Net.Mail`, but I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` and the `MailItem` in there. I found the `MailItem.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested` which is what the client's mail application has replied to and sent my user the notification.

I have the Outlook addin both as an Office2007(.Net3.5) and Office2010(.Net4) version, the 2003 has been retired. The way I see this it goes beyond office and .net version concerns.

Any light or pointers people like to share on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a ReportItem (DeliveryNotification).